# Javascript regex to replace part of substring not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, substring, match

I'm working with times and meridiems.

I could have `'2:0 a. m.'` or `'2:0 am'` or `'3:0 p. m.'` or `'3:0 pm'`
Basically what I'm trying to do is transform the **first in the second** when it happens.

My attempts:

```js
console.info('2:0 a. m.'.replace(/(.*?\s)([ampAMP]*?)/, "$1")); // 2:0 a. m.
```

This one I really don't understand...

```js
'2:0 a. m.'.replace(/(.*?\s)([ampAMP]).*?([ampAMP])/, "$1"); // 2:0 .
```

This one works but looks weird, not sure it's the best way

```js
'2:0 a. m.'.replace(/(.*?\s)([ampAMP]).*?([ampAMP]).*?$/, "$1$2$3");
```

I was barely able to remove the meridiem from the time, but how can I replace all characters not matching `[aAmMpP]` just AFTER the first space?

Comment: Perhaps you can match multiple possible formats `\b(\d+)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*([ap])\.\s*m\.` https://regex101.com/r/gkjFjs/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match am or pm, using `[ampAMP]` matches only a single character. If you use it twice, then you would allow for `mm` which is not a valid format.

You could make the pattern match more variations and capture what you want to keep. Then in the replacement use the capture groups to create the format that you want.

If the dots are mandatory:

```
\b(\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(\d{1,2})\s*([ap])\.\s*m\.
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d{1,2})` Capture **group 1**, match 1-2 digits
- `\s*:\s*` Math `:` between optional whitespace chars
- `(\d{1,2})` Capture **group 2**, match 1-2 digits
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `([ap])` Capture **group 3**, match either `a` or `b`
- `\.\s*m\.` Match `.` optional whitespace chars `m` and `.`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C4mwX6/1).

In the replacement use (as you already know that you have matched the `m` char)

```
$1:$2 $3m
```

```js
const regex = /\b(\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(\d{1,2})\s*([ap])\.\s*m\./;
[
  "2:0 a. m.",
  "2:0 p. m.",
  "3:0 p. m.",
  "3:0p.m.",
  "2:0 am"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1:$2 $3m")));
```

A bit more time like specific pattern, allowing an optional digit 0-5 for the seconds part:

```
\b([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])\s*:\s*([0-5]?[0-9])\s*([ap])\.\s*m\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9cQshK/1)

Comment: I used yours to improve mine, but yours it's even faster.
Thanks for the solution and for detailed explanation. I just added the `i` flag to deal with possibile weird formats such as `A.m.`

Comment: Ah glad you noticed you were missing the `:` in the replace!! ahah I had to try it first!

Answer (score 1):

For now after many attempts this works, alghough not very clean

```js
let time = "02:00 p. m.";
time = time.replace(/(.*?\s)([ampAMP]).*?([ampAMP]).*?$/, "$1$2$3");
console.log(time);
```

with the selected answer I had

```js
let time = "02:00 a. m.";
time = time.replace(/\b(\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(\d{1,2})\s*([ap])\.\s*m\./i, "$1:$2 $3m");
console.log(time);
```

but by the way I ended up doing this:

```js
let time = "02:00 a. m.";
time = time .replace(/\.\s*/g, "");
console.log(time);
```

because although it was good, I had performance issues.

hope it helps